# Koma Script scrlttr2 location height not matching DIN 5008 specification

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2, layout

I noticed that the height of the field "location" in Koma Script when using class scrlttr2 did not match the DIN 5008 specifications. There it should be 50mm distance from sheet edge and for the field "backaddress" it should be 45mm, which is right.

But on ym created letter the height from sheet edge to "location" field is about 40mm. So how can i fix this? Or maybe another otion for me, how can i set this height equal to the height of "backaddress", so that both texts will be in the same height?

I added a screenshot. So here you can see that the text-area on the right side (field location) starts not at the in DIN 5008 specified height of 50mm.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want to load letter option `DIN5008A` or `DIN5008B`: `\LoadLetterOption{DIN5008B}`.

Comment: You can increase your chances of getting a good answer more quickly by including the code that was used to produce the image shown in the question in the form of a short, yet fully compilable example document. That way we have something to start from and don't need to manually try to reproduce what you have so far. Such an example document is often called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864

Answer (score 4):

You can load letter option `DIN5008B` using `\LoadLetterOption{DIN5008B}` or `\documentclass[...,DIN5008B]{scrlttr2}`:

```latex
\documentclass[
  ngerman,
  fromphone=true,fromfax=true,fromemail=true,fromurl=true,
  ,DIN5008B% <- needed
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{babel}

% only to visualize the position of the address and location fields:
  \LoadLetterOption{visualize}
  \showfields{address,location}
%

\setkomavar{fromname}{Max Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Musterstr. 42\\01234 Musterstadt}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{01234 56789}
\setkomavar{fromfax}{01234 56789}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{max.muster@muster.com}
\setkomavar{fromurl}{www.muster.com}
\setkomavar{place}{Musterstadt}
\setkomavar{title}{Titel}
\setkomavar{subject}{Betreff}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Erika Musterfrau\\Musterstr. 42\\01234 Musterstadt}
\opening{Hallo}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]